# How does facebook generate the video thumbnail images?

Tags: facebook, thumbnails

When uploading a video on facebook (even video formats which are not supported by HTML5's `<video>` tag like OGV and MOV) I quickly get the choice of thumbnail from 10 of them. This is at 1-2% of upload progress so I'm wondering, how do they do it? It must be client side but how exactly?

I found out how I could potentially generate them using `<video>` and `canvas.draw()` but this only works for HTML5 supported formats. Thank you!

Comment: _“It must be client side”_ – I rather doubt that.